# How can I select a state property object name dinamically to change one of its properties(childs?) on react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a class with this state properties.

```
state = {
    step: 1,
    clientName: '',
    icecreamFlavors: {
      vanilla: false,
      chocolate: false,
      mintChocolateChip: false
    },
    toppings: {
      sprinkles: false,
      caramel: false,
      whippedCream: false
    someOtherProperty1: '',
    someOtherProperty2: ''
  };
```

---

Short version of the question without needing to read all:
how can a make the last part of this statement "dynamic". so change:
`this.state.icecreamFlavors` to `this.state.<variable-here>`

---

This properties are updated from a html form that consists of two types of fields text and checkboxes. To update the text properties I use this method.

```
handleChange = (input: any) => (e: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    this.setState({ [property]: e.target.value });
  };
```

and for the checkboxes I'm using this other method that works only for "icecreamFlavors" and that's what I want to fix (as i want to create a generic method instead of repeating the same method for every property with children):

```
handleCheckboxChange = (parentProperty: any, property: any) => (e: { target: { checked: any} }) => {
    this.setState({[parentProperty]: {...this.state.icecreamFlavors, [property]: e.target.checked} })
  };
```

This works as intended and lets me update the "icecreamFlavors" bools, but i want to make the "handleCheckboxChange" generic to be able to use it with any other property (Eg: toppings).

The html field looks like this (extract with only the checkboxes for simplicity):

```
<input
        type="checkbox"
        name="vanilla"
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange('icecreamFlavors','vanilla')}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name:"chocolate"
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange('icecreamFlavors','chocolate')}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name:"mintChocolateChip"
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange('icecreamFlavors','mintChocolateChip')}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name:"sprinkles"
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange('toppings','sprinkles')}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name:"caramel"
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange('toppings','caramel')}
      />
```

What I want to achieve is to change the "handleCheckboxChange" method to work something like this (this code does not run...)

```
handleCheckboxChange = (parentProperty: any, property: any) => (e: { target: { checked: any} }) => {
    this.setState({[parentProperty]: {...this.state.parentProperty, [property]: e.target.checked} })
  };
```

so that `...this.state.icecreamFlavors` is dynamic like `...this.state.parentProperty`

I have made some attempts like `this.setState({[parentProperty]: {...[parentProperty], [property]: e.target.checked} })` or `this.setState({[parentProperty]: {parentProperty, [input]: e.target.checked} })` but none of my attempts gives me the result I want.

If any more context or information is required please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this

```
const newObj = this.state[parentProperty];
newObj[input] = e.target.checked;
this.setState({[parentProperty]: newObj});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!!! I tried it out, but on: ```const newObj = this.state.parentProperty;``` I got this error: ```Property 'parentProperty' does not exist on type '{ icecreamFlavors: { vanilla: boolean; chocolate: boolean; mintChocolateChip: boolean;} toppings: {sprinkles: boolean; caramel: boolean; whippedCream: boolean;}};``` and on ```this.setState([property]: newObj);``` on the ```:``` I get ```',' expected.```

Comment: Sorry! Missed few brackets. Can u try now. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thnaks again. The edit fixed the last line! however I now have a couple new problems on ```const newObj = this.state[parentProperty];```, the first one is on ```this``` and it says ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type``` and the other one is on  ```parentProperty``` and is pretty much the same thing about having an any type and thast it cant be used as an index. Thanks for your patience it is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think u should change its type to `string` as the object name would always be string

Comment: Thanks for your help, took me a while to find out how to change the type. Not sure if its what you meant but I changed the state declaration to ```state: { [key: string]: any } = {<all the properties here>}``` and it solved the problem. Edit: if what I did is bad practice I would be most thankfull if you could tell me why and a better way to do it.